# Casperjs - send jQuery post

Tags: php, jquery, post, casperjs

i'm trying to send data from my Casperjs file to a php file using jQuery.post() method. This php file is then sending the received data to my local database. Here is the function that is problematic :

```
this.thenEvaluate(function(url, pseudo, zipcode, ville, prix, titre, description, date, pseudo2){
    $.post( "insertAnnonce.php", {
        url: url,
        pseudo: pseudo,
        zipcode: zipcode,
        ville: ville,
        prix: prix,
        titre: titre,
        description: description,
        date: date,
        pseudo2: pseudo2            
    });   
}, url, pseudo, zipcode, ville, prix, titre, description, date, pseudo2) ;
```

Of course I included the jQuery library and when using the debug log, it seems that the post method is not even launching. I also added the parameter : --web-security=no when running casperjs.
The problem is that nothing is sent to the database. I tested my php file manually with static variables and it worked perfectly but when using the post method, it seems that nothing is happening. Thanks for your answers

Comment: Any error on the console? Is your server receiving the call at `insertAnnonce.php`?

Comment: There is no error on the console and my server receives nothing when i'm running my casper script.